# append to end of file

Tags: c#, io, filestream, streamreader, appendto

I am trying to create a webform and one of its functions is to upload data from 4 text boxes and take new line in file and then append it to a text file and then close the file once it has been written to.

The format I have my data in the file is: 1001#Arabica#1000#01/03/2014

[order number, coffee type, amount of order, date of order], all of which are already strings.

I have already managed to work out how to read from file and this is the method I use:

```
void Read_Order_Data()
{
    FileStream fs = new FileStream("i:\\OrderData.txt", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
    StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(fs);

    while (!reader.EndOfStream)
    {
        string line = reader.ReadLine();
        string[] fields = line.Split('#');
        Order[Number_Of_Orders].Order_Number = fields[0];
        Order[Number_Of_Orders].Type_Of_Bean = fields[1];
        Order[Number_Of_Orders].Quantity_Of_Order = fields[2];
        Order[Number_Of_Orders].Date_Of_Sale = fields[3];
        Number_Of_Orders++;
    }//end of while statement
}//end of Read_Text_File()
```

I am already using System IO but don't know if I need an extra library for appending to file.

Comment: Side note: you can't really "append" to any other place of the file except after the end... It would should called "insert" in any other place and obviously requires much more involved code than `AppendAllText`. Not that Microsoft provides search engine in addition to C#, .Net and MSDN - give it a try if others fail to give you good results - http://www.bing.com/search?q=c%23+file+append

Answer (score 2):

```
 System.IO.File.AppendAllText( filename, text);
```